# Identify Components in Oven

Tags: power, relay, power-electronics, components

I am disassemblying an oven to make a reflow oven out of it. I need help identifying two components. The simplified schematic of the system is as follows:

[image: oven schematics]

Component 1 (picture below) is marked as Component ? in the schematics. Is this just a connection between the two wires or is there more to it?

[image: Component ? to identify]

Component 2 is the heat knob (picture below). A google search didn' yield much. How does this component work? Does it set the heat "PWM style"?

[image: Component 2 to identify]

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Component 1

Component 1 might be a [Thermal Cut Out](https://sinolec.co.uk/en/manual-reset-thermostat/1211842-thermal-cut-out-110c-nc.html), based upon a quick search of similar looking components. Is there any marking on the white body of component 1?

The black *button* could be a manual reset, to be used after an over temperature has occurred (and the oven has cooled down).

#### Component 2

Component 2 appears to have the manufacturers name of HUIDE. [Rising thermostatboa...](http://www.huidewk.com/en/showproducts.asp?id=2486) has the following picture which is taken from a different angle, but could be  the *heat knob*:

[image]

From the above manufacturers website can't seem to find any data nor part numbers.

Comment: thank you Chester

Comment: 1) is exactly correct. OP should not remove it, but incorporate it into whatever replacement thermostat is used (in series with the actual power to the heaters). It's a safety device.

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like a fail-safe thermal cutout, designed to limit the maximum oven temperature in the event that the primary thermostat fails. Hard to tell whether it is manual reset or one-shot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never head about a thermal cutout before but it makes a lot of sense.